# JPanel HELP to draw a bargraph

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

Does anyone know why the bars on my bargraph are showing up upside down?and what code i could add to leave a bit of room between each bar drawn? When i say upside down i mean the bars are even at the top and going down they vary in length

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
public class Panel extends JPanel
    {
    int []nums;
    String[]cat;
    String t;
    int max=0;
    int width=0;
    int height=0;
    public Panel(int []x,String[]y,String a)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            if(x[i]>max)
                max=x[i];
        }
        nums=x;
        cat=y;
        t=a;
        width=nums.length*100+nums.length*10;
        height=max*10+500;
        setSize(width,height);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Font title=new Font("TimesNewRoman",Font.BOLD,20);
        FontMetrics titl=g.getFontMetrics(title);
        g.setFont(title);
        g.drawString(t,width/2,20);
        Font label=new Font("TimesNewRoman",Font.BOLD,15);
        FontMetrics labl=g.getFontMetrics(label);
        g.setFont(label);
        for(int j=0;j<nums.length;j++)
        {
            g.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256)));
            g.drawString(cat[j],(nums.length*100)-((nums.length-j)*100)+22,height-20);
            g.fillRect(j*100,height-400,100,nums[j]*15);


        }





    }
}
```

Comment: Don't override `paint`, it's not the best method to use, consider using `paintComponent` and make sure you call `super.paintComponent` before you perform any custom painting.  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: See [good explantion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22361960/2587435) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22075683/2587435)

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is ...

```
g.fillRect(j * 100, height - 400, 100, nums[j] * 15);
```

Basically, this says to draw a rect from `j * 100` x `height - 400` that is `100` wide and `nums[j] * 15` high...

The rectangle is drawn right/down from the x/y position

You need to offset the `y` position from the `height` by the height of the bar...

```
g.fillRect(j * 100, height - (nums[j] * 15), 100, nums[j] * 15);
```

Don't override `paint`, it's not the best method to use, consider using `paintComponent`and make sure you call `super.paintComponent` before you perform any custom painting. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

Don't use `setSize` on components, any values you pass it will be reset by the parent container's layout manager.  Override the `getPreferredSize` of the `JPanel` instead.

Never assume anything about the actual size of the component from within the `paint` method, what you want and what you get won't always be the same thing.

Use `getWidth` and `getHeight` to determine the actual size of the viewable area.

Comment: so how would i fix that @MadProgrammar

Comment: @user3196301: and again as per Mad's comment, override paintComponent and call the super method. 1+

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [`fillRect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) (with my empasis):

> The **left** and right edges of the rectangle are at **x** and x + width - 1.
>   The **top** and bottom edges are at **y** and y + height - 1.

So `x` increases to the right and `y` - down.